# How to remove empty space between tables/figures and paragraphs?

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a problem that is displayed in the image attached. I have some text and then a big space since the table doesn't fit the page. It happens many times in my paper. Is there a one-off solution for this? Or everytime I shall adjust the table/figure?

This is my code for reference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{float,csquotes,booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}


\begin{document}


Since by nature principal component analysis does not identify factors
economically, I will provide evidence in support of the interpretation
I followed. Table 5 reports the highest $R^2$ obtained by regressing
each transformed data series on one of the 3 factors at a time and
correlations between the factors and the original series. Following
these results, I suggest the following interpretation: Factor 1 is
likely to represent a measure of volatility/stress in financial
conditions. It shows a positive correlation with the main volatility
indices in the EA while being negatively correlated with households
expenditure and expected GDP (1 year head). It also explains way more
than half of the variance in the EU VIX, bank spread and CISS. Factor
3 is very closely related to real activity (real GDP) in the
economy. It shows in fact a decent correlation with a variety of real
activity indices as well as price indices and explains a significant
proportion of the total variation in these variables. Factor 4 is
plausibly a measures of price pressure (inflation). It shows a high
correlation with a variety of price indices and real economic activity
indicators and explains almost hald of the overall variance in
HICP. Factor 2 is left in the end since I do not believe that a
straightforward interpretation of the factor is possible. It is
positively correlated with some idicators of financial distress (with
the puzzling exception of NFC and bank rates) and unemployment, while
it is negatively related to expected GDP and inflation. It also
explains more than half of the variance in forecasted
indicators. Since the interpretation of this factor is contentious, I
also extracted principal components only from \enquote{financial}
series. The result is the second component is approximately the same
as Factor 2. This leads to the conclusion that it is another measure
of market distress. Since I already have a robust one, I dropped
Factor 2 from the analysis.

\begin{table}[H] 
\centering 
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\textit{Factor Interpretation}}
\label{tab: tab33} 
\begin{tabular}{lllr}
\toprule & Series & $R^2$ & Corr\\ 
\midrule & Household Expenditure & 0.45 & -0.16\\ & Unemployment & 0.34 & 0.14 \\ & SPF GDP 1Y & 0.53 & -0.17 \\ & VSTOXX & 0.59 & 0.18\\  & CISS Sovereign Stress & 0.71 & 0.20\\ 
 & CISS Bond Market & 0.64 & 0.19\\ Factor 1 & CISS Money Market & 0.65 & 0.21\\ & CISS FX Market & 0.73 & 0.19 \\ & CISS Bank Volatility & 0.64 & 0.21\\ & CISS NF Equity & 0.79 & 0.19 \\ & BBB-AAA & 0.76 & 0.19 \\ & EU VIX & 0.82 & 0.18\\ & EU-USD VIX  & 0.71 & 0.16 \\ & Bank rate EA & 0.51 & 0.20 \\ & Spread bank EA vs Bund & 0.66 & 0.19 \\ \midrule & SPF INF 1Y & 0.52 & -0.24 \\ & SPF INF 2Y & 0.47 & -0.23 \\ & SPF GDP 2Y & 0.45 & -0.15 \\ & SPF Unemployment 1Y & 0.63 & 0.26 \\ & SPF Unemployment 2Y & 0.64 & 0.26 \\ Factor 2 & Spread 10Y-2Y & 0.50 & 0.23 \\ & Spread 10Y-3M & 0.44 & 0.22 \\ & Rate NFC EA & 0.41 & -0.21 \\ & Bank Rate EA  & 0.30 & -0.18\\ & Spread bank EA vs Bund & 0.28 & 0.18\\ \midrule & Business Consumer Index & 0.17 & 0.17 \\ & Industrial Confidence & 0.22 & 0.19 \\ & Manufacturing Turnover Index & 0.30 & 0.22 \\ & IP (excl. construction) & 0.28 & 0.21 \\ Factor 3 & IP (Manufacturing) & 0.27 & 0.21 \\ & New orders (Int. Goods) & 0.33 & 0.23 \\ & HICP (Total) & 0.27 & 0.21\\ & HICP (Goods) & 0.24 & 0.20\\ & PCI & 0.14 & 0.21\\
\midrule & IP (Consumer goods) & 0.21 & 0.23\\  & Real GDP  & 0.23 & 0.25\\ 
Factor 4 & HICP (Total) & 0.46 & 0.35\\ & HICP (Goods) & 0.49 & 0.36\\ & PCI & 0.20 & 0.23 \\ & Oil Brent & 0.30 & 0.28\\


\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item \textit{Note}: List of series that are best explained by a single extracted factor according to $R^2$ of a linear regression of the (transformed) series on the respective factor and have the highest correlation with the original variables.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please update your example to a full MWE, hence, that we can copy and paste it to reproduce your problem (packages, documentclass and so on are missing)

Comment: LaTeX has a mechanism of floating figures to avoid large bad spaces at page breaks, You have opted to disable that with `[H]` so _by design_ you get bad white space, and will need to move the position in the source so that it fits better with page breaking.

Comment: Fixing the code now, removing [H] doesn't change the output

Comment: @DavidCarlisle edited the questio. The code reproduces the image in the picture (in the picture is cut, in the code is in full)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle trying to fix it, in Rmarkdown works I'll do what you asked, sorry

Comment: I made the example for you this time, but not sure what answer you expect, the table is too big to fit on the first page so it goes to the second. If you had not used `[H]` and there had been some following text that text would fill up the first page. If you use `[H]` then you are preventing the table being moved after following text automatically so the white space is forced.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks so much it wasn't working on latex indeed. The problem is that following it there is a figure and then a bit of text.  I can try to move the text before the figure. Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for messing up

Comment: following figures are not a problem unless you use `[H]`, the text that follows them may be used to fill the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked,

> Is there a [global] solution for this?

Short answer: Yes. Longer answer: You should immediately cease and desist from using the `[H]` float placement specifier. E.g., change `\begin{table}[H]` to `\begin{table}[htbp]`.

Two additional comments:

- If the material in the `table` environment is quite tall, the only way that LaTeX can place it is on a page by itself.
- If you don't need to keep the tabular material on one page, i.e., if page breaks inside the tabular material are permissible, you may want to replace the `table`/`tabular` pair of environments with a [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable)
  environment.

Comment: thanks a lot! very helpful!